# How to process a Master Table?

Tags: c#, sql

Please advice for the following task in C#.net

I am having one master table and one transaction table. The master table consists the following columns..& Data..

Code  description    amount   code

101   abc            150      D (Debit)

102   def             50      C (Credit)

103   hfh            200      D (Debit)

the Transaction table contains the following Columns and Data

Code  amount   code

101      150      D (Debit)

101       60      C (Credit)

102       50      C (Credit)

102      200      D (Debit)

103      200      D (Debit)

103      100      D (Debit)

Now I have to update the master table with tranaction table data..
I have tried this at my level best and i am not getting the exact idea how to solve this. So, let me know how to solve this task in C#.net and sql server database.

Expecting a positive and quick response regarding this post.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are really wanting to do, but here is my attempt.

```
--ANSI SQL
UPDATE
  tbl_Master
SET
  amount = (
             SELECT
              SUM(amount)
             FROM
              tbl_tran
             WHERE
              code = 101
           )
WHERE
  code = 101

--T-SQL
UPDATE
  tm
SET
  amount = summd.amount
FROM
  tbl_Master tm
  JOIN (
         SELECT
          tm.Code
         ,amount = SUM(tt.Amount)
         FROM
          tbl_Master tm
          JOIN tbl_tran tt
            ON tm.Code = tt.Code
         GROUP BY
          tm.Code
       ) summd
    ON tm.code = summd.Code
```

Comment: Thank u very much for your reply.. but my task is different.. anyway u r attempt is also good.. may be it is not usefull to me..

Comment: Friend, I've read and re-read your original posting.  Perhaps you could try clarifying your question.  Here's one idea ---> you gave us the inputs, what would you like the outputs to be?